# Building REST APIs

Tags: postgresql, express, ecmascript-6

I need clear resources where I can learn about building REST APIs in nodejs,express,postgreSQL and sequelize as ORM all in ES6. The tutorial should use dummy data/JSON data first before incorporating a real db. Resources specifically in ES6 on this topic are next to non-existent. I will appreciate concise answers thanks.

Comment: It's off topic to ask for extensive, external tutorials on this site, sorry

Comment: @Neil McGuigan what do I do then?

Comment: Start here: https://www.amazon.com/RESTful-Web-APIs-Services-Changing/dp/1449358063

Comment: @BJ Safdie thanks but I will prefer something free and open source because I can't afford what I saw on that site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fortjs - an open source MVC Framework. It provides starter template project, so you can get started without spending any time on setup.

Some of the articles for fortjs are -

- Rest api in es6 -  https://medium.com/fortjs/rest-api-in-nodejs-using-es6-227765440b2b
- Rest api in typescript - https://medium.com/fortjs/rest-api-using-typescript-94004d9ae5e6

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I introduce you to my recent project [Cool-Node](http://cool-node.hyurl.com), all your needs are satisfied, and even more.

Comment: thanks I have gone through it and it looks good but I thought ES6 uses import in place of require.

Comment: Of cause you ca use import in NodeJS, but you need to install Babel, a compiler for writing next generation JavaScript.